# How to replace irrelevant data into mean values?

Tags: python, pandas, replace, mean

Let's say I have 600,000 data points in column for age. In the data there are values 0 and -1, which is not relevant for age. How can I change both 0 and -1 values in my data to the column mean value using python?

The code so far:

```py
df6 = df5['Vict Age'].replace([0, -1]).mean())
df6.update(df5)
df6
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find the mean separatly and then use the correct replace syntax to replace desired values:

```py
# Calculate mean ignoring -1, 0 values
age_mean = df5['Vict Age'][~df5['Vict Age'].isin([-1,0])].mean()
# Replace -1, 0 values
df5['Vict Age'] = df5['Vict Age'].replace({0: age_mean , -1: age_mean})
```

PS: Please use Stack Overflow code formatting instead of posting the image in the future. Thanks.

Comment: Im still getting error on executing this code.. Error name: 'numpy.float64' object does not support item assignment. How can I overcome this issue

Comment: I fixed my code. All dataframes names should be `df5`. Try again and see if the issue is solved.

Comment: The answer from @farshad  assumes 0 and -1 are relevant to the mean calculation which may or may not be true. If not then the approach should be to replace 0 and -1 with np.nan, calculate the mean and use fillna to replace with the mean.

Comment: That's a great point @user19077881 which I missed. You are right, -1, and 0 are not likely to be considered, since they are age values. I changed the code to ignore them when calculating the mean. Your approach of replacing with `np.nan` and then `fillna` would work as well.